# Openlayers 3 popup with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, popup, openlayers-3

I want to integrate Bootstrap tabs in a openlayers 3 popup (See the example: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.4.0/examples/popup.html)

The problem is the tabs doesn't work on the popup. But I find it's only when Openlayers 3 redefined the position of the popup overlay.

Comment: cant tell you why, but add `$(".nav-tabs a").click(function(){
        $(this).tab('show');
    });`

http://jsfiddle.net/oxo4c86d/12/

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for thank you. By cons I can not validate your answer. Is that what you wanted to repost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's some initailizing thing, so one way would be adding this:

```
$(".nav-tabs a").click(function(){
    $(this).tab('show');
});
```

Comment: I also need to set the 'data-target' attribute instead of href.